# Django: sort by fields and properties at the same time

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I need to order a list of instances of a particular model in a very specific way using three different model fields and a property: `field1 > field2 > property > field3`.

If they were just fields I could just do the usual:

```
queryset.order_by('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

But since I am introducing a property, I just cannot use it in `order_by`.

So what I need to do to enforce that order is ordering and grouping by each attribute and appending to the resulting list in a very ugly way:

```
lst = list(queryset)
sorted_list = []

# sort and group by field1
sorted_by_field1 = sorted(lst, key=attrgetter('field1'))
for field1, field1_grp in groupby(sorted_by_field1, key=attrgetter('field1')):

    # sort and group by field 2
    sorted_by_field2 = sorted(list(field1_grp), key=attrgetter('field2'))
    for field2, field2_grp in groupby(sorted_by_field2, key=attrgetter('field2')):

        # sort and group by property
        sorted_by_prop = sorted(list(field2_grp), key=attrgetter('property'))
        for prop, prop_grp in groupby(sorted_by_prop, key=attrgetter('property')):

            # final step: sort by the last involved attribute and extend the result list
            sorted_list.extend(sorted(list(prop_grp), key=attrgetter('field3')))
```

As you can see this is a really obtuse of ordering the original list, but I just cannot see an alternative. Is there any clean way I could do this?

Comment: Can't you just do `sorted(lst, key=lambda elem: (elem.field1, elem.field2, elem.property, elem.field3))`?

Comment: Can you do the same calculation as executed by the property in the database? If it can only be achieved in the python code, then you are not going to be able to sort it at the database level (which is what the order by call will do).

Comment: If the property is static, consider making it a field. Minor downside, major upside. If it's calculating fields, then what @wobbily_col says.

Comment: @DanielRoseman damn I totally had a lapsus and thought you couldn't sort by different fields using a lambda as the `sorted` key. I'll acept it as an answer.

Comment: @wobbily_col unluckily I cannot do it at database level

Comment: @Melvyn I wish I could introduce the field, but the scheme of the table corresponding to the model is pretty untouchable at the moment.

Comment: Can you do it using standard SQL? (Showing the code for your property would help). The Django ORM interfaces with the database and produces SQL. It then loads the results of the SQL and turns them into Django objects (each of the model instances when you iterate over the queryset). Your property is operating on the data after it is loaded into the models. If you can't do it any other way then you probably can't use the order_by() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually in the comment by @DanielRoseman:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda elem: (elem.field1, elem.field2, elem.property, elem.field3))
```

I completely missed that you could specify multiple ordering keys with a lambda expressin.